# Serious screen flickering when WiFi is on (Dell XPS 15)

Tags: wireless, graphics, intel-graphics, xps

I have a problem with a new Dell XPS 15 1050. After installation (or just using the live image) of 18.04 (and .1) and turning on WiFi, I get dramatic screen flickering every few seconds, especially when pulling data across WiFi. This includes bursts of coloured static for many seconds, artefacts, and the screen going black until a key is pressed.

I've tried multiple different combinations of graphics drivers with the same effects.

I have also tried Fedora with the same results.

I can't understand why no one else seems to have had this problem. I'd suspect a hardware problem but Windows seemed to work OK. Any ideas appreciated.

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
*-display UNCLAIMED
description: 3D controller
product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: a1
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:138 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff 


$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
logical name: wlp59s0
version: 32
serial: 9c:b6:d0:fd:9b:55
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.17.4-041704-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.2.201 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:139 memory:ed200000-ed3fffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the problem but I have little idea why.

Adding the kernel parameter...

```
 i915.edp_vswing=2
```

...eliminates the problem. I'd still be interested if anyone can explain why.

More info about the parameter in this blog post: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7Zsl522ei0QJ:https://blog.spirotot.com/2016/08/11/xps-9550-arch-linux-fix-screen-flickering/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: I spent some time trying to explain why in my answer above but unfortunately I'm not a computer engineer so it's probably laughable. Still it might get you started on the right path...

Answer (score 3):

## Solution is `i915.edp_vswing=2` kernel parameter

Although OP has solved the problem thanks to Arch Linux link in next section questions still remain about what it means.

From announcement: [Display Port Presentation December 2010](https://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/DisplayPort-DevCon-Presentation-eDP-Dec-2010-v3.pdf):

- Embedded DisplayPort (eDP) was developed to be used specifically 
  in embedded display applications

  - Notebook, Netbook, and Notepad PCs
  - All-in-One PCs
- It is designed to replay LVDS technology

As many people here already know, `i915` is Intel's display driver for Linux that has been around for decades.

The `vswing` component I cannot fathom but, you can find the C code that controls it here: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/6349211/

The parameter settings (after `=` sign) can be:

- `0`=default, to do nothing
- `1`=not sure, haven't found answer yet
- `2`=control flicker, which OP used

I will set my kernel parameter to `1` and reboot after posting this answer.

**This is a temporary setting for older kernels** according to what I read tonight. So you should occasionally remove the setting after new kernels are installed to see if it's still necessary.

Finally there is an interesting tidbit here: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9303023/

```
>   /*
> -  * FIXME On Dell XPS 13 9350 the OpRegion panel type (0) gives us
> -  * low vswing for eDP, whereas the VBT panel type (2) gives us normal
> -  * vswing instead. Low vswing results in some display flickers, so
> -  * let's simply ignore the OpRegion panel type on SKL for now.
> +  * FIXME On Dell XPS 13 9350 and Dell XPS 13 L322X the
> +  * OpRegion panel type (0) gives us low vswing for eDP,
> +  * whereas the VBT panel type (2) gives us normal vswing
> +  * instead. Low vswing results in some display flickers, so
> +  * let's simply ignore the OpRegion panel type on SKL and
> +  * IVYBRIDGE for now.
>    */
```

---

#### Original post that helped OP stumble on solution

Here is a great link for you: [Arch Linux Dell XPS 13 (9350)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9350)#Content_adaptive_brightness_control):

> **Content adaptive brightness control**
>
> In the XPS 13 the display panels (both FHD and QHD+) come with
>   adaptive brightness embedded in the panel firmware, this "content
>   adaptive brightness control" (usually referred to as CABC or DBC) will
>   adjust the screen brightness depending on the content displayed on the
>   screen and will generally be found undesirable, especially for Linux
>   users who are likely to be switching between dark and light screen
>   content. Dell has issued a fix for this however it is only available
>   to run in Windows and for the QHD+ model of the laptop so this
>   precaution should be taken before installing Linux, the FHD model of
>   the XPS 13 (9350) cannot be fixed. This is not a problem with the
>   panel but rather a problem with the way the panels are configured for
>   the XPS 13, as the same panel exists in the Dell's Latitude 13 7000
>   series (e7370) FHD model but with CABC disabled. The fix is available
>   directly from Dell.

Additionally check these posts from other Dell users:

- https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General/XPS-15-9530-screen-flicker/td-p/4360533/page/2
- [Disable Panel Self-Refresh (Windows instructions need to find Linux)](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Mouse-cursor-lagging-and-stuttering-XPS-9370/td-p/5739882/page/5)

Comment: Thanks for trying but those links weren't really relevant for the problem. However, the ArchLinux page for the XPS 15 helped lead me to the solution: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15#Graphics .

Comment: @RichSmith I love the Arch Linux web pages. They've taught me so much over the years.

Comment: I guess I'll award you the bounty for research then :) Interesting stuff, thanks.