# Screen flickering while booting - after upgrade to 18.04 with latest software update

Tags: 18.04, screen

can someone please help on this issue ?

I see that my graphics changed to llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)

I'm using Intel/AMD Radeon

How to solve this screen flickering?

Comment: To be clear after login screen appears flickering is gone?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where the flickering is occurring but I'll post one place people have experienced flicker. The solution is with a grub parameter in `/etc/default/grub`. Change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.edp_vswing=2"
```

Save the file and run `sudo update-grub`

Source:

- [Serious screen flickering when WiFi is on (Dell XPS 15)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063766/serious-screen-flickering-when-wifi-is-on-dell-xps-15/1064747#1064747)