# How do I disable all spectre/meltdown/l1tf mitigations on kernel 4.15.0?

Tags: kernel

I'm using a VPS with Ubuntu Server 18.04 with kernel 4.15.0-65-generic and I want to disable all mitigations for spectre/meltdown/l1tf/zombieland and all the other recent mitigations that degrade performance.

But is it even possible on a VPS that boots with a VPS provider's kernel?

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your VPS provider side of the question, but in my grub I use:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth loglevel=4 fastboot acpiphp.disable=1 pcie_aspm=force vt.handoff=7 i915.fastboot=1 nopti nospectre_v2 nospec mem_sleep_default=deep nouveau.nomodeset=0"


# Aug 16/2018 - i915.edp_vswing=2 comes from Ask Ubuntu Dell XPS 15 9350 screen flickering:
#               https://askubuntu.com/a/1064747/307523
# Aug 11/2018 - 10% performance boost eliminating Meltdown & Spectre support:
#               "nopti nospectre_v2 nospec"
```

I left some of the grub comments in this answer in case that helps.